# How to pass null value from a json to dynamodb

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I want to pass the value one by one to lambda function and store that the data into dynamodb but while doing that when I save the first value, the value says that the value can't be null.

I have tried the following things:

1. Add the convertEmptyValues: true

   `var doClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient({convertEmptyValues: true});`
2. Added ternary operator to pass the value, for say,

   `"age": event.age == '' ? null : event.age,`

   `"age": event.age === null ? null : event.age`

But I am getting the same error: `Error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'age' of null at exports.handler`
and the value is not getting stored in the database.

```
var AWS = require("aws-sdk");

AWS.config.update({
    region: "us-east-1",
});

var doClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient({
  convertEmptyValues: true
});

exports.handler = function(event,callback) {
    var flows =  {
        "activities": [
          {
            "gender": event.flows.activities[0].gender,
          },
          {
            "age": event.flows.activities[1].age == '' ? null : event.flows.activities[1].age,
          },
          {
            "zipCode": event.flows.activities[2].zipCode == '' ? null : event.flows.activities[2].zipCode,
          },
          {
           //More Code
          },
        ]
      };
}
```

Comment: From the error you get it seems that `event.flows.activities[1]` is `null`. You should make sure that the function gets the expected values.

Comment: The function will get the value after I pass the value, for till then it should pass as a null value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're checking the wrong thing for a null value. The ternary expression you use does not have any effect --- having `age: x.age === null ? null : x.age` is exactly the same as having `age: x.age`.

In your case, however, the problem is that in the expression `x.age`, the value of ***`x`*** is `null`, which means you're trying to access the `age` property of `null`, which leads to an error. What your ternary expression should check for is whether `x` itself is `null`.

This is how your code should look:

```
const AWS = require("aws-sdk");
AWS.config.update({
    region: "us-east-1",
});
const doClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient({
    convertEmptyValues: true
});

exports.handler = function(event,callback) {
    var flows =  {
        "activities": [
        {
            "gender": event.flows.activities[0].gender,
        },
        {
            "age": event.flows.activities[1] === null ? null : event.flows.activities[1].age,
        },
        {
            "zipCode": event.flows.activities[2] === null ? null : event.flows.activities[2].zipCode,
        },
        {
        //More Code
        },   
   ]
};
}
```

Comment: If I want to skip the step if the value is null, can I do that? @Kalev